# Subspace Clustering didn't show any plot in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to show Clique plot from Subspace Examples, but the plot does blank, not even a single node is drawn from a respective dimensions

```
library(subspace)
library(ggvis)
data("subspace_dataset")
summary(subspace_dataset)
a <- CLIQUE(subspace_dataset,xi=40,tau=0.06)
plot(a, subspace_dataset, size=0.1)
plot(a, subspace_dataset, color_by = "mix",
     standardcolors = c("#1F77B4", "#FF7F0E", "#2CA02C", "#D62728", "#9467BD",
                        "#8C564B", "#E377C2", "#7F7F7F", "#BCBD22", "#17BECF", "#000000"),
     tooltip_on = "hover", ...)
```

[image]

[image]

does anyone facing this similiar issues? can anyone tell what could be the problem? Thanks in advance