# Understanding R subspace package clustering output

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, feature-selection

Somewhat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783266/subspace-clustering-didnt-show-any-plot-in-r) question.

I am using R [subspace](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/subspace/index.html) package for subspace clustering. As in the question above, I have failed to use the generic plotting method to plot out my resulting clusters in a way native to the package. The next step is to understand the output of the command

```
CLIQUE(df, xi = 40, tau = 0.2)
```

That looks something like this:

[image: large list of lists]

I understand that the "object" is the row number for the clustered unit, and the subspace indicates the dimensions of the data in which the clustering was done. However I don't see how the clusters in the given dimensions can be distinguished.

The documentation does not contain information on the output. Ideally, my goal is to plot out all the clusters with something like `ggplot2`, or in 3D, what have you. And I need to know which units are in which clusters in corresponding dimensions.

Additionally, checked if the dimensions of any of the two members of the output list are the same like this:

```
cluster_result <- clique_model
equalities_matrix <- matrix(
  0L, nrow = length(cluster_result), ncol = length(cluster_result)
)
for (i in 1:length(cluster_result)){
  for (j in 1:length(cluster_result)){
    equalities_matrix[i,j] <- (
      all(cluster_result[[i]]$subspace == cluster_result[[j]]$subspace)
    )
  }
}
sum(equalities_matrix)
```

The answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what my researches lead to, might be helpful for someone in the future.

Above, the CLIQUE algorithm above outputted one cluster per every set of dimensions, possibly by the virtue of the data or tuning of the algorithm. I added more features to the data, ran it again, and checked if the dimensions of any of the two members of the output list are the same again. This time, yes, several dimensions were the same as the `sum(equalities_matrix)` yielded a number larger than the number of features.

In conclusion, the output of the algorithm is a list of lists where each member list represents one cluster in one subspace:

subspace ... the dimensions making the subspace indicated with TRUE,

objects ... members of the cluster.

If there is more than one cluster in a given subspace, there will be more member lists with the same subspace, and different members of the cluster.

Here are the papers that helped me understand the theory:

- [Parsons, Haque, and Liu; 2004](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.969.7082&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [Agrawal Gehrke, Gunopulos, Raghavan](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/johannes/papers/1998/sigmod1998-clique.pdf)